# encrypt mysql data and pass through hyperlink, then decrypt on the next page?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, hyperlink

I am using the following encryption method to encrypt my MySQL data / string like so:

```
$string = $row['reference'];
       $secret_key = "PlowFish";
// Create the initialization vector for added security.
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
// Encrypt $string
$encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret_key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
```

I am then passing the encrypted string through a hyperlink like so:

```
<a href="ns_application.php?ns_request='.$encrypted_string.'"><p>Click'</p></a>
```

I am then trying to decrypt the string and echo out the original value onto the next page like so:

```
$enc = $_GET['ns_request'];
$secret_key = "PlowFish";
// Create the initialization vector for added security.
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
$decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret_key, $enc, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

Your reference is: <?php echo $decrypted_string; ?>
```

however this is not working as it still echo's the encrypted value rather than the decrypted value. please can someone show me where I am going wrong. Thank you

Comment: Just an observation: have you considered sessions and found them not being feasible?

Comment: Sessions (or some other token based mechanism with server side storage) would be a far less troublesome way to pass data between pages without letting the user see or edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to be honest, I didn't test the enc/decryption above and now that I have I can see it is still garbage. Here is a little class you can use if you want.

```
class encryption{
    private $config;

    public function __construct( $options=array() ){
        $this->config=array_merge(
            array(
                'cipher'    =>  MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
                'mode'      =>  MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,
                'key'       =>  FALSE,
                'iv'        =>  FALSE,
                'size'      =>  FALSE,
                'base64'    =>  TRUE,
                'salt'      =>  FALSE
            ),
            $options
        );
    }
    private function getivs( $config=object ){
        $config->size=mcrypt_get_iv_size( $config->cipher, $config->mode );
        $config->iv=mcrypt_create_iv( $config->size, MCRYPT_RAND );
    }
    public function encrypt( $data=NULL ){
        $config=(object)$this->config;
        $this->getivs( $config );
        $data=trim( $data );
        $module = mcrypt_module_open( $config->cipher, '', $config->mode, '' );
        mcrypt_generic_init( $module, $config->key, $config->iv );

        $output = $config->base64 ? base64_encode( mcrypt_generic( $module, $data ) ) : mcrypt_generic( $module, $data );

        mcrypt_generic_deinit( $module );
        mcrypt_module_close( $module );
        return $output;
    }
    public function decrypt( $data=NULL ){
        $config=(object)$this->config;
        $this->getivs( $config );
        mb_detect_order( 'auto' );
        $encoding=mb_detect_encoding( $data );
        if( !$data or is_null( $data ) or empty( $data ) or !$encoding or $data=='' or base64_decode( $data )=='' ) return FALSE;

        $module = mcrypt_module_open( $config->cipher, '', $config->mode, '' );
        mcrypt_generic_init( $module, $config->key, $config->iv );

        $output = $config->base64 ? rtrim( mdecrypt_generic( $module, base64_decode( $data ) ),"\0" ) : rtrim( mdecrypt_generic( $module, $data ),"\0" );

        mcrypt_generic_deinit( $module );
        mcrypt_module_close( $module );
        return urldecode( $output );
    }
}//end class
```

use it like this:-

```
$enc=new encryption( array( 'key'=>'PlowFish' ) );
$encrypted_string = $enc->encrypt( $string );
echo $encrypted_string.BR;
$decrypted_string=$enc->decrypt( $encrypted_string );
echo $decrypted_string.BR;
```

Comment: I get the following MySQL error: call to a member function decrypt() on a non object on this line: $decrypted_string=$enc->decrypt( $encrypted_string );

Comment: @RamRaier nevermind I got it working, misspelled a letter, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to base64_encode the data before sending in a url and then base64_decode before trying to decrypt using mcrypt. Encrypted text contains characters that are not url safe and thus get mangled.

```
$string = $row['reference'];
$secret_key = "PlowFish";
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
$encrypted_string = base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret_key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv) );


$enc = base64_decode( $_GET['ns_request'] );
$secret_key = "PlowFish";
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
$decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret_key, $enc, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

Your reference is: <?php echo $decrypted_string; ?>
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback, I am really new to php and so don't have much idea about the types of encryption available. Would you please be able to offer me a bit more of an idea of how I would go about using base64 encoding?

Comment: $data=<encrypted data>;
$urlsafe=base64_encode( $data );

Comment: thank you I managed to get this working, however is there anyway u can increase the characters in this encryption to say 16 digits rather than just the 7 or so being displayed atm? for instance can this be increased to base85?

Comment: base64_encoding is not encrypting - it is merely ensuring that the data is tramsnittable via http without getting mangled. The encryption is done with mcrypt and, as you are using 256bit encryption it would appear to be fairly secure

Comment: apologies I was on about something completely different, I structured my code in the completely wrong way but looking at your example now I see where I went wrong. Thank you for your help

Comment: ok I've tried your code now using the base64 encryption but it still shows the reference as encrypted on the next page. have you managed to get the code working at your end? I don't know what I am doing wrong in that case